# Get TimeStamp value of Array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime

I have an array of dates that have the datetime values till microseconds .

So myquestion is that how can I convert those values to a Timestamp values such as in the form of integer or float no's
as the following type:

```
1578032412798
```

Here I have the array of dates as following :

```
var dates =["2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.232000"] ;
```

I am trying the following code. but it's not working :

```
 dates.forEach((e) => {
  var date = e.getTime();
  console.log (date)});
```

Also I tried to implement the following mwthod. but its showing the values till hours only:

```
var dateString = dates,
                     dateTimeParts = dateString.split(' '),
                     timeParts = dateTimeParts[1].split(':'),
                     dateParts = dateTimeParts[0].split('-'),
                   date;
                   x = new Date(dateParts[2], parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) - 1, dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);

mainval  = x.getTime();
```

Comment: why there is `14` in month of dates array?

Comment: 12 is the date value not month
yy-dd-mm @Kaushik

Comment: do you expect an array of timestamps are your result?

Comment: yes. kind of @NickParsons. Just want to convert array of datetime into timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to extract the year, month and day parts of the date and then create a new `Date` from a reconstructed string with them in the correct order:

```js
var dates = [
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000", 
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000", 
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000",
  "2020-14-03 11:14:48.232000"
];
res = dates.map(d => {
  m = d.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (.*)$/);
  return new Date(`${m[1]}-${m[3]}-${m[2]} ${m[4]}`).getTime();
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` with `.split()` to reformat your dates. First `.split()` by space to get the date, and then `.split()` the date by `-` to get the date components. You can then flip the day and month around and join that back into a datetime string. Using `new Date()`, you can then get the timestamp from the reformatted date string:

```js
const dates =["2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.232000"];

const res = dates.map(date_str => {
  const [date, rest] = date_str.split(' ');
  const [y, d, m] = date.split('-');
  return +new Date([[y, m, d].join('-'), rest].join(' '));
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: does it also contains the microsecond value

Comment: yes, it takes that into consideration. As you can see, all your dates are exactly the same except for the microseconds. If it didn't contain the microseconds then all the timestamps would be the same, but they're different

Answer (score 0):

Please refrain from using the `var` keyword. Use `const` and `let` instead.

The following code should suit your usecase, at least if all the dates you provide follow the same format (`yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss:SSSS`):

```js
const timestamps = dates.map(e => {
  const year = e.substring(0, 4);
  const day = e.substring(5, 7);
  const month = e.substring(8, 10);
  const hours = e.substring(11, 13);
  const minutes = e.substring(14,16);
  const seconds = e.substring(17, 19);
  const milliseconds = e.substring(20);
  return new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds).getTime();
});
```

It's not as fancy as using a regex, but it's a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing dates as string in a array, store the Date object itself. If you push the Date object into a array, it will be very useful to extract milliseconds and all the functions related to Date object can be used.